# ImportError: cannot import name 'DummyVecEnv' from 'stable_baselines3.common.envs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinforcement-learning

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.common.envs import DummyVecEnv
from gym import spaces
```

When importing DummyVecEnv, I am getting the following error. Kindly help me to solve the problem.

```
Input In [1], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 from stable_baselines3 import DQN
----> 5 from stable_baselines3.common.envs import DummyVecEnv
      6 from gym import spaces

ImportError: cannot import name 'DummyVecEnv' from 'stable_baselines3.common.envs' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\envs\__init__.py)
```

Comment: What version of stable_baselines3 do you have?  According to https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/blob/master/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/__init__.py, I think it should be ```from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv```.

Comment: I have installed version 2.9 of stable_baselines3. I tried with "from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv" and it works fine. However, when running this env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: StockTradingEnvironment(stock_data)]), it gives the error as "ValueError: The environment is of type <class '__main__.StockTradingEnvironment'>, not a Gymnasium environment. In this case, we expect OpenAI Gym to be installed and the environment to be an OpenAI Gym environment."

Comment: That's a different error.